# Facebook pixel ViewContent with Google Tag Manager not firing on Angular 2 navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to track the views on my website using Facebook Pixel, Google Tag Manager and Angular 2 App.
After implementing everything correctly the problem is when i navigate from one page to another the ViewContent event is not registered. Only when i reload the page it track the event.

I think is a problem with angular2 app.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation has detailed step-by-step guide how to track page views in single page applications:

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/05/29/tagging-a-single-page-application-facebook-pixel/